# mysql_real_escape_string conversion to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

Ok I would like to know how you convert this mysql code into mysqli.

```
function protect($string) {
return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(addslashes($string)));
}
```

I know you change mysql to mysqli but it asks for 2 parameters this worked with mysql so I would like to see it in mysqli

also I haven't yet found someone on stackoverflow with a question about the new mysqli version so I wasn't able to find out myself

Comment: You should go directly for PDO instead of mysqli

Comment: I just want to know what it is in mysqli

Answer (score 2):

It is better not to use it at all!

`mysql_real_escape_string()` was a hack which was used to prevent SQL injection, and it didn't even do that 100%. This function was never meant to protect anything. It is a simple string formatting function.

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` is yet another hack to make the transition easier. Although, at the time of writing this post `mysql_*` has been deprecated for so long, that no one should have any excuse to use some kind of shim for transitioning, because everyone should already be using MySQLi with prepared statements or even better PDO.

As for `strip_tags()` and `addslashes()` they are useless in this context and only mutilate your data. Don't use them.

To protect against SQL injection, one should use prepared statements and ensure that no variable input is inserted into SQL directly.

For example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT columnA FROM tableB WHERE columnC=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $someVariable);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "pword", "db");

function protect($string) {

    return $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags(addslashes($string)));

    }
```

**EDIT**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "aaa");
$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);

echo($city);
```

Comment: I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in /

Comment: did you created your connection OOP way: $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "pword", "db");

Comment: function connect() {
  new mysqli("host","username","password","dbname");
}

Comment: that function must return, then assign reference to created object to vaiable: $mysqli = connect(); function connect(){return  new mysqli("host","username","password","dbname");}

Comment: $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "aaa");
$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);

echo($city);

Answer (score 0):

This function is a bad idea.

Using `strip_tags()` and `addslashes()` indiscriminately on all incoming data needlessly  mutilates it, with zero added security.

- To feed data into the database, use only the string escaping function, [`real_escape_string()`.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
- To display data from the user on a HTML page, strip the tags *then* or use `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid any scripting attacks.

Comment: I still want to keep the function

Comment: At least lose the `addslashes()`. It serves no purpose whatsoever except that it turns every `'` into `\'`.

Comment: ok but 
function protect($string) {
return $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags);
}
still wont work

Comment: Of course not. Where is your $mysqli reference in that function?  function protect($string,$mysqli) { return $mysqli->real_escape_string(strip_tags); }